# WCF service migrating from VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: wcf

I have migrated WCF services from VS 2008 to VS2010. The service is not working and it is throwing exception when i am trying to access the service URL.

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="NHSIC.Sutton.Web.Global"
    Language="C#" %>
```

[HttpException]: Could not load type 'Web.Global'.
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError)

Thanks,
Nabin

Comment: Looks like your problem is with the general start up of the application, since your error is coming from global.asax.  Can you provide more information about the environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating the virtual service in IIS under IIS settings (remove then create button should appear)